# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory while reading a tsv file

Tags: python-2.7, csv, github, google-colaboratory

I am using a raw data path from GitHub in my code but it still shows no such file or directory.

[image: 1]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before asking a question. Do not post screenshots of text.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) to make a HTTP request and get data from a website. `open` only works for files in your filesystem.

You need to use a library like [urllib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request) or [requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) to make a HTTP request and get the files from GitHub.

Example for requests:

```py
r = requests.get(Path[filename])
tsv_content = r.text
```